# Define variable local to function

Tags: emacs, let, cursor-position

I am working (joyfully) working through the *Introduction to Emacs Lisp Programming* and have solved the first [8.7 Searching Exercise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/search-Exercises.html#search-Exercises).  It states,

> Write an interactive function that searches for a string. If the
>   search finds the string, leave point after it and display a message
>   that says “Found!”.

My solution is

```el
(defun test-search (string)
  "Searches for STRING in document.
Displays message 'Found!' or 'Not found...'"
  (interactive "sEnter search word: ")
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (setq found (search-forward string nil t nil))) 
  (if found
      (progn
        (goto-char found)
        (message "Found!"))
    (message "Not found...")))
```

How do I make `found` be local to the function?  I know that a `let` statement defines a local variable.  However, I only want to move point if the `string` is found.  It's not clear to me how to define `found` locally, yet not have the point be set to the `beginning-of-buffer` if the `string` isn't found.  Is `let` the proper command for this situation?

Comment: You should indeed be using `let` for temporary-scope variables (which are local to the scope of the `let` form, but not local to the *function* unless lexical-binding is in use and the variable is not otherwise marked as dynamic).

Comment: e.g.: `(let ((found (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (search-forward string nil t nil)))) (if found ...))`

Comment: Alternatively, you might leave point alone after a successful search, but restore the original position after an unsuccessful one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in some comments, `let` is what you want to use here, although it will *not* define a variable local to the *function*, but a scope of its own.

Your code becomes:

```
(defun test-search (string)
   "Searches for STRING in document.
Displays message 'Found!' or 'Not found...'"
   (interactive "sEnter search word: ")
   (let ((found (save-excursion
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (search-forward string nil t nil))))
     (if found
       (progn
         (goto-char found)
         (message "Found!"))
       (message "Not found..."))))
```

*Edit: code modified thanks to [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils)'comment.*

Comment: Note that you should use `(goto-char (point-min))` rather than `(beginning-of-buffer)` when writing elisp.

Comment: Thank you @phils ;)