# Local to `let` versus local to a function

Tags: emacs, scope, elisp

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197337/define-variable-local-to-function/43275115#43275115) regarding local variable definitions in Elisp, both respondents advise that `let` is appropriate and emphasize that it will not define the variable to be local to the *function*.  The variable is local only to the `let` statement.

What is the distinction between local to `let` and local to the function?  Is there another construct which would define the variable for the scope of the function?

The function using a `let` statement looks this:

```
(defun test-search (string)
  "Searches for STRING in document.
Displays message 'Found!' or 'Not found...'. Places point after word 
when found; fixed otherwise."
  (interactive "sEnter search word: ")
  (let ((found (save-excursion
         (beginning-of-buffer)
         (search-forward string nil t nil))))
    (if found
        (progn
          (goto-char found)
          (message "Found!"))
      (message "Not found..."))))
```

Comment: `let` creates a local variable. that's the only way to create it in elisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `let` makes up the whole body of your function in your example, your "variables local to let" are indistinguishable from "variables local to the function".

For that reason, no there is no separate construct to introduce variables local to a function.  `let` is that construct, which can be used for variables valid over the whole function, or for variables valid over a small subset, depending on where you place the `let`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the distinction between local to let and local to the function?

The question is slightly open to interpretation, but here I am interpreting "local to the function" as meaning that code which is not *part of the function* cannot see the variable, and *by default* in Emacs that is not the case for a `let` binding (or indeed for variable bindings in general).

To understand in detail you need to understand the difference between *dynamic binding* and *lexical binding* (and there are good explanations of this elsewhere, so you can follow this up yourself). To briefly demonstrate the difference, however, consider the following functions:

```el
(defun func1 ()
  (let ((foo 42))
    (func2)))

(defun func2 ()
  (bound-and-true-p foo))
```

The result of `func1` is the result of `func2`, which in turn depends on whether a variable `foo` is visible to the latter function.

Under the default dynamic binding, calling `func1` will return `42`, because the scope of the binding of `foo` is the duration of the `let`, which incorporates the call to `func2`.

Under lexical binding, calling `func1` will return `nil`, because `foo` (which has not otherwise been declared dynamic) has a binding which is local to `func1` and therefore `func2` cannot see it).

I'm actually being slightly misleading when talking about "local to the function" with respect to the above example, as the scope of the `foo` binding is strictly the scope of the `let` form rather than the scope of the *function*. The behaviour is not restricted to only `let` bindings though, so we could also use the following example, comparing the result of `(func3 42)` under dynamic and lexical binding:

```el
(defun func3 (foo)
  (func4))

(defun func4 ()
  (bound-and-true-p foo))
```